# How can I get my homepage URL in Django views.py?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying some condition in my code:

```
If request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == 'www.example.com/':
    # code here
else:
    return redirect('/')
```

Writing the full path `https://www.example.com/` also works, but I need Django itself do.

**Is there any way that Django itself return my homepage URL ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) and [resole](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) if you name your homepage correctly.

Out of curriosity, what are you trying to do with this ?

Comment: Can you give some idea? at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012417/how-can-i-get-the-previous-url-in-django